install solr on docker container, ubi9
I am trying to build the SOLR program into UBI9.. below is the Dockerfile
Dockerfile
FROM ubi-9:latest
ENV SOLR_USER=solr
ENV SOLR_HOST=solr
    
RUN mkdir /opt/src
COPY /solr-9.7.0-src.tgz /opt/src
RUN cd /opt/src && \ 
        tar -zxvf solr-9.7.0-src.tgz
    
COPY /solr-9.7.0.tgz /opt

I need to execute the below command (docker run -itd) to deploy and install the solr using the below command
docker run -itd solr-app /usr/sbin/init

command that I used to install the solr service inside the container manually..
/opt/src/solr-9.7.0-/solr/bin/install_solr_service.sh
My question is how can I put the /usr/sbin/init into the docker-compose or Dockerfile... The reason why I use this command because whenever I run the install_solr_service.sh file, it will prompt an error system has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. .. Is there anyway I can put the /usr/sbin/init inside the docker-compose so that systemd can boot first? then after that, I can execute the install_solr_service.sh somewhere...
Sorry if my question is not clear...

In a container you don't usually run a full init system or an init script or a service file; you just directly run the program as the Dockerfile CMD.  A systemd service file especially won't work well, since systemd wants to manage so much of the kernel and physical-device environment; it's very much the wrong tool for a container environment.
